# Hard drive is getting some read errors, best way to get as much data off it as possible?

Tags: windows-7

Any recommended software?

Answer (score 1):

Send it to a professional Data recover service if the data is "mission critical".

If thats not an option try GRC spinrite on the drive it has worked wonders for some people. That may be able to repair bad sectors on the drive and let you get more data off.

Comment: Nah, it's not mission critical. Just trying to salvage as much as possible. GRC Spinrite... isn't that software old and outdated?

Comment: Its not outdated, im not sure if it supports 4k sectors (if this is relevant in your case) but steve gibson is a dedicated and intelligent man, im sure his software will continue to work as long as we have physical drives. 

His site my appear to be old and outdated but he keeps it minimal and free of faf for 56k modem users. As he does with his security now podcast.

Not that i condone this, but find a copy and try it on your drive and if it works go buy the software. What do you have to loose ?